# Installing easy_install, NOT SO EASY

Tags: python, path, beautifulsoup, easy-install

I am trying to install easy_install in order to use BeautifulSoup...  However I have no clue what my PATH directory is... when I run        easy_install BeautifulSoup.. I get

error: Not a recognized archive type: C:\docume~1\tom\locals~1\temp\weasy_install-w6haxs\BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz

I am guessing this has something to do with the PATH that is not set up right in Environment Varibales..... But I have no clue what my Path should be... 
Any help would be appreciated... I am very new to all of this so speaking english rather than programming would be appreciated lol..

Comment: Try `pip` instead of `easy_install`. That looks like a `easy_install`-specific error.

Comment: Have you got something installed that can handle .tar archives? Perhaps http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ will help.

Comment: That issue looks like even though you are on a windows system, its trying to download a gzipped version of the source, and cant extract it. +1 for using PIP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install beautifulsoup is exactly what I did yesterday. These steps work for my windows 64:

- Download and run ez_setup.py at 
  http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
  This will install easy_install.exe to python scripts directory. For me it is C:/python26/scripts
- CD to C:/python26/scripts
- Run easy_install.exe pip
  This will install pip.
- Then run pip install beautifulsoup4 to get beautiful soup.

Be sure to allow these tools access to the Internet in your firewall program.

Answer (score 0):

Try install a binary version:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#Base

and there are lots of binary packages~ choose the suitable version and type for you.

Comment: pip is superior to easy_install with the only exception of not being able to install binary packages. That's why if you are able to install some package with pip you should prefer this to installation with easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

I'd Try to download the source .py files, find the setup.py files and run in command line: `<path_to_source_archive>\setup.py install`
this usually works when easy_install stutters.